# How to add an annotation to MKMapView using an MKPointAnnotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, mapkit

I am trying to figure out how to add an instance of MKAnnotation to a MKMapView. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...everything seems to go fine until I actually try and add the annotation to the mapView. Then I receive a SIGABRT error. Here is my code:

```
lon = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];
lat = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
 MKPointAnnotation *point;
 CLLocation *theLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
 CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
 location.latitude = lat;
 location.longitude = lon;
 [point setCoordinate:(location)];
 [point setTitle:businessName];

 //ITS RIGHT HERE THAT I GET THE ERROR
 [theMap addAnnotation:point];
```

Do you have to set the region of the map first or something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to alloc and init `point`:

```
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
```

Comment: Oh dang I feel dumb, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks very much